# Actions are getting called infinitely when making API calls in redux-react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to show loading until all the components inside the RootContainer completes their api calls, But my application is running in infinte loop of dispatch action getting called ,and  the application remains in loading state always. It made around 1300 calls in 30 secs. Here is my code. I am not able to find why the application is running in an infinte loop.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RootContainer from './components/RootContainer'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <RootContainer/>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )

  }
}

export default App;
```

**RootContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToprops} from './mapFunctions.js'
import UserContainer from './UserContainer'
import TodoContainer from './TodoContainer'

class RootContainer extends React.Component{
  render(){
    if(this.props.userData.count===0){
      return (
        <div>
          <UserContainer/>
          <TodoContainer/>
        </div>
      );
    }else{
      return(
        <h2> Loading... </h2>
      )
    }

  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToprops)(RootContainer)
```

**UserContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToprops} from './mapFunctions.js'

class UserContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
        userList:[]
      }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(data =>{
          this.setState({
            userList:data
          })
        })
    }

    render(){
        console.log("count = "+this.props.userData.count);
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>User List</h2>
            <ul>
                {this.state.userList.map(item => {
                  return <li>{item.name}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToprops)(UserContainer)
```

**TodoContainer.js**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import { fetchUsers } from '../redux'
import {mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToprops} from './mapFunctions.js'

class TodoContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state={
        todoList:[]
      }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos').then(data =>{
          this.setState({
            todoList:data
          })
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>ToDo List</h2>
            <ul>
                {this.state.todoList.map(item => {
                  return <li>{item.title}</li>;
                })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToprops)(TodoContainer)
```

**UserActions.js**

```
import { INCREMENT_COUNT ,DECREMENT_COUNT} from "./userTypes"
import axios from 'axios'

export const incrementCount = () =>{
    return {
        type:INCREMENT_COUNT
    }
}

export const decrementCount = () =>{
    return {

        type:DECREMENT_COUNT
    }
}

export const fetchUsers = (url) =>{
    console.log("fetchUsers called" + url)
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(incrementCount())
        return fetch(url)
               .then(response => {
                 dispatch(decrementCount());
                 return response.data
               })
               .catch(error => {
                const errorMsg = error.message
                console.log("error = "+errorMsg)
                dispatch(decrementCount());
              })
    }
}
```

**UserReducer.js**

```
import  {INCREMENT_COUNT ,DECREMENT_COUNT} from "./userTypes"

const initialState = {
    count:0,
}

const reducer = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case INCREMENT_COUNT:
            console.log("reducer called =increment")
            return{
               count: state.count+1,
            }
        case DECREMENT_COUNT:
            return{
                count:Math.max(0,state.count-1),
            }
        default: return state
    }
}

export default reducer
```

**mapFunctions.js**

```
import { fetchUsers } from '../redux'

export const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        userData: state.user
    }
}
export const mapDispatchToprops = dispatch =>{
    return {
        fetchUsers: (url) => dispatch(fetchUsers(url))
    }
}
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import userReducer from './user/userReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
    user:userReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk,logger))
)

export default store
```

Comment: if I were you, I would make codesandbox for better help

Comment: If you can put this project in a sandbox, that would be great!

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mj306) . I have put the project in sandbox, please use the link to refer it.

Answer (score 0):

> But my application is running in infinte loop of dispatch action
>   getting called ,and the application remains in loading state always.
>   It made around 1300 calls in 30 secs. Here is my code. I am not able
>   to find why the application is running in an infinte loop.

*Update:* Refactored `redux` functionality into separate components with a new action to check if there are any API calls in progress. Here is a perfectly working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/redux/store.js).

```
//UserActions.js
import * as types from "./actionType";
import { beginApiCall, apiCallError } from "./apiStatusAction";
import { handleResponse, handleError } from "./apiUtils";

export function fetchUsersSuccess(users) {
  return { type: types.LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS, users };
}

export function fetchUsers(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(beginApiCall());
    return getUsers(url)
      .then((users) => {
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(apiCallError(error));
        throw error;
      });
  };
}

export function getUsers(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(handleResponse).catch(handleError);
}
```

```
//apiStatusAction.js
import * as types from "./actionType";

export function beginApiCall() {
return { type: types.BEGIN_API_CALL };
}

export function apiCallError() {
return { type: types.API_CALL_ERROR };
}
```

This reducer checks if there are any actions with substring `_SUCCESS` still in progress. If yes, the `initialState` is incremented by one else its decremented.

```
import * as types from "../actions/actionType";
import initialState from "./initialState";

function actionTypeEndsInSuccess(type) {
  return type.substring(type.length - 8) === "_SUCCESS";
}

export default function apiCallStatusReducer(
  state = initialState.apiCallsInProgress,
  action
) {
  if (action.type == types.BEGIN_API_CALL) {
    return state + 1;
  } else if (
    action.type === types.API_CALL_ERROR ||
    actionTypeEndsInSuccess(action.type)
  ) {
    return state - 1;
  }

  return state;
}
```

This is how you can leverage the `apiStatus` reducer to render a spinner in your component.

```
//UserContainer.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchUsers } from "../redux/actions/UserActions";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

function UserContainer() {
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const loading = useSelector((state) => state.apiCallsInProgress > 0);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchUserList = () => {
    dispatch(fetchUsers("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")).catch(
      (error) => {
        alert("Loading users failed" + error);
      }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserList();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      {userList.map((user) => {
        return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserContainer;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But my application is again running in an infinite loop if I write dispatch(decrementCount()), in your editted code inside try block, as it was written in my original code.

Comment: Hey @ayushi, I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/components/TodoContainer.js). Please check it out.

Comment: Hi @Ajin, the project is working fine beacuse the actions are not getting called because of the wrong usage. My requirement is to show loading until both the apis calls gets completed, for that I need to call dispatch(incrementCount()) ( at start of try ) and dispatch(decrementCount()) (before return in try), when I am adding these actions in your userActions.js file , I am running in the same error again. Removing these functions does not fulfil my requirement.

Comment: Hey @ayushi, I think it got lost in translation. So I've created a new [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-rain-9dd65?file=/src/components/RootContainer.js) which dispatches action and refactored redux components and added a new `apiCallsInProgress` action to check if there are any `api` calls in progress.